# Where to ask about reasons for a mismatch of aerial photo to on-the-ground photo

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a photo taken on the ground along a street and the matching aerial photo showing the rows of houses. There is one house with the roof seemingly turned in the wrong direction 90° - there is no reason why one of the photos would be doctored, so my guess is some weird optical illusion in one of them. Would GIS, Photography, Neuroscience, or some other SE site be best for this?

The question would look like this:

---

Google Maps has this aerial photo (c 2022), notice the gable of the roof being/seeming north-south:

[image]

The street in a recent news image (20.03.2022), imaged south-to-north, seems to show/shows the gable running east-west:

[image]

Which of these images was interpreted wrongly by me?

Comment: Add your exact question please. This is too vague

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look with [streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.4697603,4.1241168,3a,75y,14h,80.1t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sOYcK7o5cs9BjUSIQFdqhhA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)... Camera angles can obscure a lot.

Comment: @Luuklag - thanks for the input - i now added the questionas i was planning to ask it

Comment: @Cerbrus Streetview does indeed clear it up. Aerial-visible N-S gable is obscured by a high wall, which, on the ground photo, blends into the E-W gable. This also explains the weird shadow on the roof in the aerial shot. Neat. thx

Comment: I think you are comparing two different roofs, in the [aerial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48ycU.jpg) and [streetview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsGSu.jpg) - so it's a bit no-repro; if you agree. In that event I wouldn't recommend any site.